# C++ Custom exception throw () in constructor

Tags: c++, exception

So I read that you aren't supposed to have anything other than basic types in a custom exception class because otherwise it might throw an exception within the exception (like a dream within a dream). And that you should throw by value and catch by ref.

I have this as my exception class header:

```
class DeepthroatException : public std::runtime_error {
  public:
  DeepthroatException(const char* err); // set err member to err

  private:
  // Error description
  const char* err;
};
```

But I dont like it since it introduces an issue with memory management, which is invisible to the naked eye and I need to use a mine detector. I would like to change to an `std::string` if possible.

But then there is the issue in the first paragraph above, so I thought about doing this:

```
#include <string>
class DeepthroatException : public std::runtime_error {
  public:
  DeepthroatException(std::string err) throw(); // set err member to err, no throw

  private:
  // Error description
  std::string err;
};
```

Is this ok to do?

Comment: You can pass the string parameter on to `runtime_error` and let it handle the problem.

Comment: @BoPersson yes but I am doing some extra things in the constructor, such as setting error codes. The code above is simplified. I was asking if there is a way to guarantee that no extra exceptions can be thrown even with a non basic data type such as string, or is this not possible?

Comment: You can set error codes and then call the `runtime_error` constructor.

Comment: If you build a `string` you risk a `bad_alloc` exception if the system is *totally* out of memory. Saying `throw()` doesn't help if the code still throws, it only makes it worse. You might ask yourself if you want to try to handle this case, or if you can live with the `bad_alloc` (which is probably going to happen real soon anyway).

Comment: For your first version exception constructor "DeepthroatException(const char* err)", I think it's very well. You can pass a string to it without memory management such as DeepthroatException("My error message"). "My error message" is in read only memory space, so DeepthroatException needn't manage it memory space, it's enough to save the address in "const char* err".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::string` can also give you a bad time with `std::bad_alloc`. But that problem is already inherent to `std::runtime_error`, as its constructors can take a `std::string` as an argument:

```
explicit runtime_error( const std::string& what_arg );
explicit runtime_error( const char* what_arg );
```

It's only this way because copying exceptions shall never throw, so the implementation will likely allocate another string and copy the argument's content to it. If you really don't want a second exception being thrown, mark your constructor as `noexcept` and make sure it never fails, and if it ever do, your program will be shut down immediately.

You can inherit `std::runtime_error` behavior by just constructing it with a string from your constructor like so:

```
DeepthroatException(const std::string& err) noexcept :
    std::runtime_error(err)
{
    // ...
}
```

At this point, you can remove your `err` data member, as `runtime_error`  will give you the internal string which you can refer to by `what()`.